# how to show localStorage objects in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

I want to display the data I have stored in `localStorage`.

I want to display array of objects that I stored in `localStorage` of "My Cart" HTML page, where it will display that data when the "Add to Cart" button is clicked.

```
function addToCartClicked(event)
{
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    //var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    //var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    //var imgSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src

    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

    var newItem = 
    {
    'product-name': shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText,
    'product-image': shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src,
    'product-price': shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    };

 oldItems.push(newItem);

 localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));

}


function displayCart()
{

}
```

Comment: There is everything you need in your question. Just call displayCart(); from "addToCartClicked(event)".

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayCart()
{
  const items = localStorage.getItem('itemsArray');

  if (items) {
   const parsedItems = JSON.parse(items);
   // Do Stuff With parsedItems 
  }
}
```

Comment: Dont post solution directly.Give some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data from localstorage using the key that you used to save, in this case 'itemsArray'

You've already used the getItem method to get the values

Use the same again as follows :

```
let returnedValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray'));
```